# Atom running Hydrogen Package - No introspection available

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter, atom-editor, hydrogen

I am running Python3 in Atom on MacOS.  Inside Atom, I can run the Hydrogen package and I can use toggle-inspector to pull up the docstrings for some functions (like sorted and enumerate) but for many other built in and imported functions, like `append` and `insert`, I get a `No Introspection Available` error.  The functions for which doc strings are available all seem to be colored aquamarine while all other functions are colored blue.  How do I get docstrings for all functions?

Note: I added this to my keymap.cson but I still get the same error

```
 'atom-text-editor:not([mini])':
  'shift-tab': 'hydrogen:toggle-inspector'
```

Comment: What are the functions exactly? `append` and `insert` aren't builtins, but maybe you meant `list.append` and `list.insert`?

Comment: Did you run the code in Hydrogen before toggling the inspector? Some things need to be run before they can be inspected. FWIW, from a bit of testing, the only thing that can never be inspected is `[].append`. If you could provide some example code, like a [mre], that would help a ton. BTW I'm not sure what's going on with the coloring.